# help me to elaborate this solution with counterexample?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p\ge5 $ be a prime. Then which of the following satement is correct:

1. $\mathbb{F_p\times\mathbb{F_p}}$ has atleast five subgroups of order p.
2. Every subgroup of $\mathbb{F_p\times\mathbb{F_p}}$ is of the form ${H_1\times{H_2}}$ where ${H_1 , {H_2}}$ are subgroups of $\mathbb{F_p}$.

I was find this answer  on this site that

(1) is true.  Consider any element $x(k,n) = (nk\pmod p) \times k$ with $0\leq n<p$ and $k\neq 0\pmod p) $. It is easy to see that $x(k,n)$ gnerates a cyclic subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_p \times \Bbb{Z}_p$.  It is also easy to show that the group generated by  $x(k,m)$ does not contain $x(k,n)$. Thus there are $p$ distinct subgroups of this form.

i was reading this solution ,,,but im not getting anything  in my head nor im not  understand this solution,,,,,,Can any body elaborate this solution with detail and in understanding form i mean with counter example,,,i will be glad if anybody help me...thanks in advance

Comment: How many subgroups of $\mathbb F_p\times\mathbb F_p$ **are** of the form $H_1\times H_2$ where $H_1,H_2$ are subgroups of $\mathbb F_p$?

Answer (score 1):

The argument to (1) can be simplified: The (additive) group $\Bbb F_p\times \Bbb F_p$ is of order $p^2$, but is not cyclic. Hence all elements of $\Bbb F_p\times \Bbb F_p$ (except $(0,0)$) are of order $p$. Then for each of the $p^2-1$ non-trivial elements, the group generated by it is cyclic of order $p$. But as a cyclic group of order $p$ has precisely $p-1$ generators, each subgroup is counted $p-1$ times. Hence in total, $\Bbb  F_p\times \Bbb F_p$ has $\frac{p^2-1}{p-1}=p+1\ge 6$ subgroups of order $p$.

On the other hand, $\Bbb F_p$ has only two subgroups in total: the trivial group and itself. Hence there are only $2\cdot 2=4$ possible choices for subgroups $H_1,H_2$ to make a subgroup of the form $H_1\times H_2$.

Comment: thanks a lots @ Hagen von Eitzen........last paragraph im not getting liitle bits....that it has 4 possible choices for subgroup H1,H2,,,that mean  option 2 is correct .Is it true ?